# Monodevelop F5 greyed out and can't run/debug program on 32bit Ubuntu 18.04 install

Tags: c#, linux, mono, monodevelop, 32-bit

I have recently started to do some light development on a 32bit netbook running Ubuntu 18.04.

Python IDEs like IDLE work fine but if I try to develop C#, I run into problems. I have installed Mono and Monodevelop using the package manager.

`sudo apt install mono && sudo apt install monodevelop`

I have used this IDE successfully before on other platforms but I can't get it to debug, compile and run C# programs.

The F5 (run debugging)option is greyed out on the idea so I can't even run a simple Hello World type program.

I have tried to install the .NET libraries manually but they are not available for this architecture anymore.

I can use the Mono framework to compile C# manually from the command line but so far that is all I can do.

Has anyone else got C# development working on a 32bit Linux/Unix platform either using Monodevelop or VS Code?

I have also tried VS Code with a similar problem and older versions of Jetbrains Rider won't work because they are not compatible with 32bit JVM.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check /var/log folder for errors.